# Schwarschild Metric from Kepler law

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, orbital-motion, metric-tensor

Can we redrive Schwarschild metric from Kepler's law without assuming General Relativity?

Answer (score 4):

Somewhat surprisingly there is a sort of derivation of the Schwarzschild metric from Kepler's third law. Rather than give the (lengthy!) details here let me refer you to [this article that works through the calculation](https://www.mathpages.com/rr/s5-05/5-05.htm).

But this is not really a derivation because it assumes that the $r$ in Kepler's law is the same as the Schwarzschild $r$ coordinate, and this is not the case. It also assumes that the $t$ in Kepler's law is the same as the proper time, and again this is not true.

The result is a coincidence due to the way the Schwarzschild $r$ coordinate has been chosen There are several such coincidences. For example we have the coincidence that the event horizon position is the value of $r$ for which the Newtonian escape velocity is equal to the speed of light, and again this is due to the way the Schwarzschild $r$ coordinate has been chosen.

Comment: Also the shapirodelayed orbital velocity observed at infinity is the same as under Newton (see https://www.astro.umd.edu/~miller/teaching/astr498/lecture10.pdf#page=4), without the perihelion shift of course.